# how to retrieve an aray of only specific attributes in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where I need to retrieve an array of specific attributes from a table. I have a TransportAttendanceBlock table. In the table I have blocked(boolean) and blocked_date attributes. From a controller I am fetching this table by passing params of date and boolean value.

```
Controller code:
    @blocked_date = TransportAttendanceBlock.by_blocked_date_and_blocked(@today,1)
Model
  named_scope :by_blocked_date_and_blocked, lambda{|date,status| {:conditions=> {:blocked_date=>date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month, :blocked=>status}}}
```

Here in the controller I am getting the entire objects of TransportAttendanceBlock table.
But I need to just pass any array of dates only in the @blocked_date variable as json. 
So how do I extract only blocked_date attributes and assign it to @blocked_date variable. Please help. I am using rails2.3 and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@blocked_date = TransportAttendanceBlock.by_blocked_date_and_blocked(@today,1).map(&:blocked_date)
```